# How can variable field width be implemented with printf()?

Tags: c, printf

The question is :

> How can variable field width be implemented using `printf()`? That is, instead of `%8d`, the width should be specified at run time.

I came across some C code on the Internet based on the question above but as I am new to C programming I haven't been able to make heads or tails of the code.
I am posting the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char text[] = "Hello world";
   int i;
   for ( i = 1; i < 12; ++i )
   {
      printf("\"%.*s\"\n", i, text);
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you, the code you have shown is about controlling the *precision*, not the field width. For a *shortened* form<sup>**</sup>

```
 %A.B<format specifier>
```

`A` denotes the field width and `B` makes the precision.

Now, quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` (*emphasis mine*)

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After the %, the following
>   appear in sequence:
>
> [..]
>
> - An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the `d`, `i`,
>     `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversions, the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point
>     character for `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, and `F` conversions, the maximum number of significant
>     digits for the `g` and `G` conversions, **or the maximum number of bytes to be written for `s` conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an
>     asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional decimal integer**; if only the period is
>     specified, the precision is taken as zero. If a precision appears with any other
>     conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.

and

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
>   this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision. [...]

So, in your case,

```
printf("\"%.*s\"\n", i, text);
```

the precision will be supplied by `i` which can hold different values at run-time.

---

The complete format <sup>(broken down in separate lines for ease of readability)</sup>

```
%
<Zero or more flags>
<optional minimum field width>
<optional precision>
<optional length modifier>
<A conversion specifier character>
```