# Using a #define in a formatted printf to define precision

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PREC 4

int main()
{
    long l = 12;
    printf("%PRECld", l);
}
```

How would I be able to use `PREC` to define the precision wanted? i.e. the expected output would be `0012`. Currently printing `%PRECld`.

Comment: Hint: [The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: @SteveSummit: I don't think this counts as a duplicate; [How can variable field width be implemented with printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693901/how-can-variable-field-width-be-implemented-with-printf) is asking about one specific technique, but someone who is trying to use a macro defined value isn't necessarily trying to use dynamic field width formatting.

Comment: In case you were wondering, the reason that `PREC` doesn't get replaced with `4` in your example is the preprocessor never performs substitutions inside of quoted strings.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Maybe I'm old fashioned, but in my mind, *the* way to get a "variable" field width is with `%*` -- and that's even if the associated "variable" is a compile-time constant.  It's a frequently-asked question, with a canonical answer.  With that said, I like your answer as an alternative, and I was glad you posted it.

Comment: See other answers at [How can variable field width be implemented with printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693901/how-can-variable-field-width-be-implemented-with-printf).

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yeah, I generally agree that `%*` is usually the way to go (my own answer does mention that the performance cost of runtime precision is trivial in the context of I/O), but I figured as long as they're using old-style macro constants (rather than the more commonly used/"proper" `static const` variables that are otherwise safer and provide the compiler with more information, at the expense of not allowing their values to be inlined into a string at compile time, and preventing replacement by compile flags), macro stringification should be mentioned, even if it's uglier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand the macro to make it part of a compile time format string, you'll need a stringification macro (yes, the two layers are necessary; if you only defined `#define STR(x) #x`, `STR(PREC)` would insert the string `"PREC"`, not `"4"` as you want):

```
#define _STR(x) #x
#define STR(x) _STR(x)
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
printf("%0" STR(PREC) "ld", l);
```

That will be expanded by the preprocessor to:

```
printf("%0" "4" "ld", l);
```

and since adjacent string literals are treated as a single string, it ends up compiling as if you directly typed:

```
printf("%04ld", l);
```

For a runtime solution, you use `*` to set precision dynamically from an argument, with no need for a stringification macro:

```
printf("%0*ld", PREC, l);
```

In theory, this is slightly slower at runtime, since it needs to parse a more complex format string, pass and receive more arguments, etc., but in practice I/O is so expensive that the cost of a little CPU fiddling is trivial in comparison.

Note the added `0` in both versions, to make it pad with zeroes, not spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward:

```
int main()
{
    long l = 12;
    printf("%*ld", PREC, l);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the field width formatting as you normally would with `*`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PREC 4

int main()
{
    long l = 12;
    printf("%*ld", PREC, l);   // "  12"
    printf("%0*ld", PREC, l);  // "0012"
}
```

See the [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) reference and look for `field width`.